# REACT: Unable to update children props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having troubles updating the header class so it updates it's className whenever displaySection() is called. I know that the parent state changes, because the console log done in displaySection() registers the this.state.headerVisible changes but nothing in my children component changes, i don't know what I'm missing, I've been trying different solutions for some hours and I just can't figure it out what i'm doing wrong, the header headerVisible value stays as TRUE instead of changing when the state changes.

I don't get any error code in the console, it's just that the prop headerVisible from the children Header doesn't get updated on it's parent state changes.

Thank you!

```
class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      section: "",
      headerVisible: true,

    }
    this.displaySection = this.displaySection.bind(this)
  }

  displaySection(sectionSelected) {
    this.setState({ section: sectionSelected }, () => {
      this.sectionRef.current.changeSection(this.state.section)
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        headerVisible: !this.state.headerVisible,
      })
    }, 325)

    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('this.state', this.state)
    },500)
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Layout>
            <Header selectSection={this.displaySection} headerVisible={this.state.headerVisible} />
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

```
const Header = props => (
  <header className={props.headerVisible ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}>
       <div className="navbar-item column is-size-7-mobile is-size-5-tablet is-uppercase has-text-weight-semibold">
              <span onClick={() => { this.props.selectSection("projects")}}>
                {" "}
                Projects
              </span>
  </header>
)
```

Comment: How do you verify that the class name doesn't change? FWIW, if you compute state based on existing state, always pass a function to `setState`: `this.setState(state =>({headerVisible: !state.headerVisible}))`.

Comment: Using the React Developer Tools of Chrome I can see changes in props and states.

I see that the state of IndexPage changes, but there is no change in Header props.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: You are never calling the selectSection function. Why don't you try calling it before return the page content?

Comment: Yup, true, tried to simplify the code for the question and i ommited it, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seemed to be a couple of issues with your example code:

1. Missing closing div in Header
2. Using `this.props` instead of `props` in onclick in span in Header

The below minimal example seems to work. I had to remove your call to `this.sectionRef.current.changeSection(this.state.section)` as I didn't know what sectionRef was supposed to be because it's not in your example.

```js
class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      section: "",
      headerVisible: true,

    }
    this.displaySection = this.displaySection.bind(this)
  }

  displaySection(sectionSelected) {
    this.setState({ section: sectionSelected })

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        headerVisible: !this.state.headerVisible,
      })
    }, 325)

    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('this.state', this.state)
    },500)
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
            <Header selectSection={this.displaySection} headerVisible={this.state.headerVisible} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Header = props => (
  <header className={props.headerVisible ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}>
       <div className="navbar-item column is-size-7-mobile is-size-5-tablet is-uppercase has-text-weight-semibold">
              <span onClick={() => { props.selectSection("projects")}}>
                {" "}
                Projects
              </span>
       </div>
  </header>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <IndexPage />,
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
);
```

```css
.visible {
  opacity: 1
}

.invisible {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a markup error in your code in Header component - `div` tag is not closed.
Also, I suppose, you remove some code to make example easy, and there is artifact of `this.sectionRef.current.changeSection(this.state.section)` cause `this.sectionRef` is not defined.

As @Felix Kling said, when you change the state of the component depending on the previous state use function `prevState => ({key: !prevState.key})`

Any way here is a working example of what you trying to achieve:

```
// @flow
import * as React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";

type
Properties = {};

type
State = {
    section: string,
    headerVisible: boolean,
};

class IndexPage extends React.Component<Properties, State> {

    static defaultProps = {};

    state = {};

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            section: "",
            headerVisible: true,

        };
        this.displaySection = this.displaySection.bind(this)
    }

    displaySection(sectionSelected) {
        setTimeout(
            () => this.setState(
                prevState => ({
                    section: sectionSelected,
                    headerVisible: !prevState.headerVisible
                }),
                () => console.log("Debug log: \n", this.state)
            ),
            325
        );
    }

    render(): React.Node {
        const {section, headerVisible} = this.state;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Header selectSection={this.displaySection} headerVisible={headerVisible} />
                <br/>
                <div>{`IndexPage state: headerVisible - ${headerVisible} / section - ${section}`}</div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default IndexPage;
```

and Header component

```
// @flow
import * as React from "react";

type Properties = {
    headerVisible: boolean,
    selectSection: (section: string) => void
};

const ComponentName = ({headerVisible, selectSection}: Properties): React.Node => {
    const headerRef = React.useRef(null);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <header ref={headerRef} className={headerVisible ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}>
                <div className="navbar-item column is-size-7-mobile is-size-5-tablet is-uppercase has-text-weight-semibold">
                    <span onClick={() => selectSection("projects")}>Projects</span>
                </div>
            </header>
            <br/>
            <div>Header class name: {headerRef.current && headerRef.current.className}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default ComponentName;
```